# Bash, copy files from folder to another

Tags: linux, bash, file, copy, directory

I have a problem with an Uni OS Course assignment.
Basically the task says:

> Deliver now a file for assessment. The content of the file is: one line, containing a command that
>   copies all files with prefix "2016", from directory "ExercisesOS" to directory "OSLab".
>   Consider the current directory to be "~" when writing such command.

I have already tried with that code:

```
cp /ExercisesOS/2016* /OSLab
```

but it performs me two error.

How can I write the correct command?

Comment: what are the two errors?

Comment: `cp /ExercisesOS/2016* OSLab`. I guess `/OSLab` does not exist (root dir!!)

Comment: the command you've used will look for those directories from root level, I suppose they are in `~` instead which is also your cwd... so just remove leading `/` from both paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to copy from the directory you are working.

To check where you are working:

```
$ pwd
/home/userdir
```

To copy from your working directory:

```
$ cp ExerciseOS/2016* OSLab/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir OSLab && cp /ExercisesOS/2016* OSLab
```

This solution would assume that the directory 'OSLab' isn't already created.